# C++ Function is printing unwanted numbers after endl (memory variable?)

Tags: c++, function, output

this code is working perfectly for me except for one small issue. After calling on my `find_min` and `find_max` functions, the code also prints out a seemingly random number. I think this has to do with pass by reference, and its a memory value or something. Can somebody explain and tell me how to get rid of it? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

//get_avg function will get the average of all temperatures in the array by using for loop to add the numbers

double get_avg(int* arr, int n) {
    double res = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        res += arr[i];

    }
    return (res/n); //average
}

void get_array(int* arr){
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<25; i++){
        arr[i] = (rand() % 100) + 1;
    }
}

//prints the results of get_avg in and get_array in table format, then finds difference between avg and temp.

void print_output(int* arr) {
    double avg = get_avg(arr, 24);
    cout << "The average is: " << avg << endl;
    cout << "Position\tValue\t\tDifference from average\n\n";
    char sign;
    for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++){
        sign = (avg > arr[i])?('+'):('-');
        cout << i << "\t\t" << arr[i] << "\t\t" << sign << fabs(avg-arr[i]) << endl;
    }
}

//finds the minimum function using a for loop

int find_min(int* arr, int n) {
    int low = arr[0];
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<n; i++){
        if(arr[i] < low){
            low = arr[i];
            index = i;

        }
    }
    cout << "The position of the minimum number in the array is "<< index <<" and the value is " << low << endl;    
}

//finds the maximum function using a for loop

int find_max(int* arr, int n){
    int hi = arr[0];
    int index;
    for(int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
        if(arr[i] > hi) {
            hi = arr[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    cout << "The position of the maximum number in the array is "<< index <<" and the value is " << hi << endl;
}



int main(){

    int arr[24]; //declares array


    get_array(arr);
    print_output(arr);
    cout << find_min(arr, 24) << endl; 
    cout << find_max(arr, 24) << endl;

    cout << endl;


    // wrap-up

    cout << "This program is coded by Troy Wilms" << endl;  // fill in your name

    // stops the program to view the output until you type any character

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your `find_min` and `find_max` are declared as returning `int`, but do not return anything. Also consider using `std::array` (or `std::vector`) and its `.size()` instead of magic numbers.

Comment: In the `get_array` function you use `for(i=0; i<25; i++){` while everything else uses `24` as the array size.

Comment: Using `endl` sometimes make problems. Use `\n` is the better one for any situation.

Comment: @AliSepehri-Amin, in *any situation* it is definitely not better. `endl` flushes the buffer, and sometimes you need to flush it. So they are different and one does not substitute for the other.

Answer (score 5):

in this two lines :

```
cout << find_min(arr, 24) << endl; 
cout << find_max(arr, 24) << endl;
```

you are using `std::cout` to print the returning value of these functions (which is int), but in your function definition you are not returning any value, So it will print a garbage value.

at the end of your functions (`find_min` and `find_max`) add `return arr[index];`

Comment: as a curiosity: why the standard does not qualify this as an error? I mean, declaring a function return something and not return anything in the body of the function. An implicit `return somegarbage` seems to never be a useful behaviour

Answer (score 1):

As was already pointed out in another answer, the problem lies in not returning a value from a function declared to return one. So a great part of the solution here is to read and understand your compiler's warnings!

Even better, turn compiler warnings into errors (e.g. with GNU g++ by using the option `-Werror`.

Other comments suggested to use "real" C++ types, e.g. `std::vector` as a container for the "array", instead of using the C-style array of integer and use some magic constants when iterating over the collection. This is all correct and can even be put further: Know C++ standard library well and use it! Why programming functions that get minimum and maximum value of a collection, when these functions are already available?

An attempt to avoid these pitfalls and provide a version that is more C++-like, see the following example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <ios>  // I/O manipulators
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

using Container = std::vector<int>;

// get_avg function will get the average of all temperatures in the container
double get_avg(const Container& c) {
    // force promotion from int to double by using 0.0 as initial value!
    return std::accumulate(c.begin(), c.end(), 0.0) / c.size();
}


// fill container c with 'count' random values, originally get_array()
void fill(size_t count, Container& c) {
    std::srand(std::time(0));

    size_t i = 0;
    while (i++ < count) {
        c.push_back((rand() % 100) + 1);
    }
}

//prints the results of get_avg in and get_array in table format, then finds difference between avg and temp.
void print_output(const Container& c) {
    double avg = get_avg(c);

    std::cout << "The average is: " << avg << endl;
    std::cout << "Position\tValue\t\tDifference from average\n\n";

    size_t idx = 0;
    for(auto e : c){
        cout << idx++ << "\t\t" << e << "\t\t" << std::showpos << avg - e << std::noshowpos << std::endl;
    }
}

// There is std::minmax_element that gets both minimum and maximum value at once!
void print_min_max(const Container& c) {
    auto mm = std::minmax_element(c.begin(), c.end());
    std::cout << "The position of the minimum number in the container is "<< mm.first - c.begin() <<" and the value is " << *(mm.first) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The position of the maximum number in the container is "<< mm.second - c.begin() <<" and the value is " << *(mm.second) << std::endl;
}   

int main() {

    Container c;
    const size_t count = 24;

    fill(count, c);
    print_output(c);
    print_min_max(c);

    std::cout << endl;

    // wrap-up

    std::cout << "This program is coded by Troy Wilms" << endl;  // fill in your name

    // stops the program to view the output until you type any character

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `24` in the `print_output` is obviously a misprint. :)

Comment: @Evgeny You're right, thanks for the hint. I eliminated now even this magic number.